# Force move of pattern-matched Option

Tags: rust

I have the following code for a toy Blackjack program:

```
fn winner(self) -> Option<Player> {
    let mut ranking: Vec<_> = self.players.iter().filter(|p| p.score() <= 21).collect();
    ranking.sort_by(|a,b|a.score().cmp(&b.score()));
    match ranking.pop() {
        Some(ranking_first) => match ranking.pop() {
            Some(ranking_second) if ranking_second.score() == ranking_first.score() => None,
            _ => Some(ranking_first),
        },
        None => None,
    }
}
```

I'm deliberately consuming the game to return a winner. I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:126:27
    |
126 |                 _ => Some(ranking_first),
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Player`, found &Player
    |
    = note: expected type `Player`
               found type `&Player`
```

I'd like to force a move of the player so that it will still be available after the game is dropped. I could simply implement Clone / Copy for this example, but I'd like to understand why this is happening. Is there a way to match Some() using move instead of ref? Thanks.

Comment: Use `let mut ranking: Vec<()> = ...` to check the type of `ranking`; I suspect it is `Vec<&Player>` because `iter` returns an iterator over references.

Comment: Yep, as Matthieu M. said, you seem to want `into_iter()` rather than `iter()`.

Comment: Yeah that was it. Thanks. How do I mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: @spease You don't, but you can ask the commenters to provide an answer. If they don't care to do that, it is perfectly fine to [write an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (giving credit where appropriate) and accept it.